# Convert character column to a list within the data frame

Tags: r

When I read the csv file into **df**, **SoftwareOwner** is a character column

```
> df
   Software    SoftwareOwner
   <chr>       <chr>
1  I-DEAS      Siemens
2  TeamViewer  Autodesk, TeamViewer, Siemens
3  Inventor    PTC, Google, SpaceClaim, Bricys
4  AutoCAD     Autodesk
```

I want to make **SoftwareOwner** a list within this data frame so I tried the simple solution

```
> df$SoftwareOwner <- as.list(df$SoftwareOwner)
```

But all this did was make each entry in the column a list with one entry

```
> df$SoftwareOwner[2]
[[1]]
[1]  "Autodesk, TeamViewer, Siemens"
```

I've tried adding parameters like *sep = ","* and *all.names = TRUE* to *as.list* but neither worked. Is there any way to access just *Autodesk* or *TeamViewer* or *Siemens* when calling something like what I have just above?

Comment: Please post the output of `dput(head(df))`

Comment: I've seen the format you want, but I believe it is not something found in base R. Why don't you just convert your data.frame to a list of lists? Data.frames in R are essentially lists with some restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Might I recommend making Siemens, Autodesk, Teamviewer, etc. their own columns and coding a 1 or 0 to indicate ownership?  In my experience this is a far more flexible approach.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution :

```
# recreate your data.frame
df <- read.csv(text=
"Software;SoftwareOwner
I-DEAS;Siemens
TeamViewer;Autodesk, TeamViewer, Siemens
Inventor;PTC, Google, SpaceClaim, Bricys
AutoCAD;Autodesk",sep=";")


df$SoftwareOwner <- lapply(strsplit(as.character(df$SoftwareOwner),split=','),trimws)


# > df$SoftwareOwner
# [[1]]
# [1] "Siemens"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Autodesk"   "TeamViewer" "Siemens"   
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "PTC"        "Google"     "SpaceClaim" "Bricys"    
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "Autodesk"


# > df$SoftwareOwner[[2]][3]
# [1] "Siemens"

# > df$SoftwareOwner[[3]][2]
# [1] "Google"
```